# logback.xml in spring boot not printing debug messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

New to logback. I'm trying to print debug and info messages to external file.

I'm reading the configuration from this file

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\SH_DashboardCES\\Logs\\Dashboard.log"/>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="pe.com.dashboard" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Printed Dashboard.log

```
2020-04-06 16:18:37,362 INFO pe.com.claro.postventa.dashboard.Application [main] Starting Application v1.0.0 on HPERLAPVALDK with PID 17808 (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\SH_DashboardCES\Dashboard-1.0.0.jar started by valdezkj in C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\SH_DashboardCES)
2020-04-06 16:18:37,365 DEBUG pe.com.claro.postventa.dashboard.Application [main] Running with Spring Boot v2.2.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.4.RELEASE
2020-04-06 16:18:37,365 INFO pe.com.claro.postventa.dashboard.Application [main] No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-06 16:18:52,651 INFO pe.com.claro.postventa.dashboard.Application [main] Started Application in 15.828 seconds (JVM running for 16.296)
```

Java Class implementing logback

```
package pe.com.dashboard.dao;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.util.*;

    @Repository
    public class ClarifyDaoImpl implements ClarifyDao {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClarifyDaoImpl.class);


        @Override
        public ConsultaTipificacionOutputMapper consultaTipificacion(ConsultaTipificacionInputMapper request) throws DBException {
            logger.info(INICIO_TRANSACCION + nombreMetodo);

            logger.debug(INPUT_PARAMETERS + request.toString());

            return null;
        }
    }
```

None of the messages in the java class is printed even when the log level of the package is set to DEBUG.

Answer (score -1):

```
<root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
</root>
```

log level ： trace < debug < info < warn < Error

you can change level to debug

Comment: By changing the log level where you suggest I'm only printing Spring log in my file but not the actual message I'm trying to log in my java class.

Comment: that doesn't work as pointed out above.